# How to use Mocha and Jest with TypeScript without conflicts?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, jestjs, jstestrunner

I'm trying to install Mocha and Jest with types on one project. We use strict typecheck, so I get errors related to conflicting globals type.

I've tried to create ambiguous module declaration, defining only Mocha in `types` at `tsconfig`. I've been trying to remove Jest's declaration - but that would partially help. Disabling strict typecheck or lib check is not an option.

I expected to work it properly, but instead got the next errors.

```
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(29,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'beforeEach' must be of type 'HookFunction', but here has type 'Lifecycle'.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(31,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'afterEach' must be of type 'HookFunction', but here has type 'Lifecycle'.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(32,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'describe' must be of type 'SuiteFunction', but here has type 'Describe'.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(34,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'xdescribe' must be of type 'PendingSuiteFunction', but here has type 'Describe'.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(35,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'it' must be of type 'TestFunction', but here has type 'It'.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(37,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'xit' must be of type 'PendingTestFunction', but here has type 'It'.
node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts(38,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'test' must be of type 'TestFunction', but here has type 'It'.
node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(926,15): error TS2430: Interface 'Global' incorrectly extends interface 'MochaGlobals'.
  Types of property 'describe' are incompatible.
    Type 'Describe' is not assignable to type 'SuiteFunction'.
      Types of property 'only' are incompatible.
        Type 'DescribeBase' is not assignable to type 'ExclusiveSuiteFunction'.
          Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Suite'.
```

Even removing all types from Jest gets me this error:

```
node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(926,15): error TS2430: Interface 'Global' incorrectly extends interface 'MochaGlobals'.
  Types of property 'describe' are incompatible.
    Type 'Describe' is not assignable to type 'SuiteFunction'.
      Types of property 'only' are incompatible.
        Type 'DescribeBase' is not assignable to type 'ExclusiveSuiteFunction'.
          Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Suite'.
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That's quite sad

Answer (score 3):

As of August 2019, this appears to have been fixed on [`master`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/8571), but a new version has not been released yet.

In the meantime, I was able to address these errors by adding the following to one of my definitions:

```js
declare module '@jest/types/build/Global' {
  interface DescribeBase extends mocha.SuiteFunction {}
  interface ItBase extends mocha.TestFunction {}
}
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for this answer. We are facing the same issue. Where/to which file should I add this statement? I don't understand what you you mean by "one of my definitions". Thanks.

Comment: @MattG you should be able to put it in any file, such as perhaps one of your testing setup files or type definition files.

Comment: This didn’t work for me unfortunately. Still seeing the same error.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Didn't do a thing, actually. Same errors. Plus it only works if there's a one to one function mapping. In some cases, mocha uses two classes for things that are in a single class in jest.

Answer (score 1):

I searched through package lock file to see which dependencies use `@types/jest` and found out that in my case I still have `ts-jest` in my project which I removed and conflicts disappeared