# How can I use Cypress (with Mocha) and Jest in same project?

Tags: jestjs, mocha.js, cypress

In my project I'd like to use Cypress for browser-based tests and Jest for other tests. So I included both packages in my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "cypress": "^4.8.0",
  "jest": "^26.0.1"
  // ...
}
```

When writing the Cypress tests the functions like `describe` or `it` are taken from Mocha which Cypress seems to be based on. But how do I need to configure my project so that I can use Jest for the non-Cypress tests?

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask about. They are different frameworks that need differently written test suites and shouldn't interfere. Configure Jest like always and prevent it from accessing Cypress tests (e.g. *.e2e.js). Same for Cypress.

Comment: A while ago Cypress had @types/mocha as dependency insetead of devDependecy which was causing an issue with jest and Typescript, but it seems to be fixed now. What is the problem that you're facing with both libraries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Mocha and Jest with TypeScript without conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56181799/how-to-use-mocha-and-jest-with-typescript-without-conflicts)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Thanks for the link. Indeed, it does provide some further information. Couldn't work on the original issue for a while so I'll need to check it out.

Comment: Sorry for the automatically created unintentional question - the comment should be read as  [“Possible duplicate”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339563/the-auto-comment-does-this-answer-your-question-generated-when-voting-to-clos)